# Method which uses a dictionary to change a corresponding self value in python

Tags: python, class, dictionary, methods, pass-by-reference

As the title indicates, i'm looking to create a method which changes a self variable according to a value in a dictionary.  This is a bit difficult for me to articulate, so let's illustrate it with an example below:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = "something"
        self.baz = "something else"

    def change_a_value(self, new_value): #let's assume new_value is a list with the first item being the value we want to change, and the second being what we want to change it to.
        values = { "bar": self.bar, "baz": self.baz }
        values[new_value[0]] = new_value[1] # i want this to set self.bar to the second item in new_value

myClassInstance = Foo()
myClassInstance.change_a_value(["bar", "something new"])
print(myClassInstance.bar) # i want this to return 'something new', but it still returns 'something'
```

Is it possible to do what i'm trying to do?  Is there some easier, more graceful way to do it?  I want to avoid creating functions like `change_bar` and `change_baz` for abstraction purposes, but if that's the cleanest way to do it, that's okay.

Comment: What's wrong with `myClassInstance.bar = 'something_new'`?

Comment: @evsheino: As i said, abstraction.  I included `self.baz` to indicate that i might want to use the same function for another attribute as well, so having `change_a_value` only set `myClassInstance.bar` would force me to create another method to handle `baz`.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you'd want your object to have a function for simply changing any of its values. I do realize that sometimes it's useful to be able to do it in an indirect way via `setattr`, and I hope your use case warrants this, but having a function called `change_a_value` that does nothing more than the name suggests does not seem very useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the `setattr` function:

```
setattr(self, new_value[0], new_value[1])
```